# I want to make a matrix of 17 X 12 colums or i can say , i want to put a iteration of following elementsfor 17 times

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, computer-vision

A is a 17 by 12 matrix

```
A=[ X1, Y1, Z1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -x1.X1, -x1.Y1, -x1.Z1, -x1 ;

     0, 0, 0, 0, X1, Y1, Z1, 1, -y1.X1, -y1.Y1, -y1.Z1, -y;
   ....]
```

I want to make a matrix like this with **17 rows** , and their index being changed 17 times

```
e.g 1, 2, 3, 4, ...17
```

I'm trying to calibrate camera manually by taking pictures of 3d body , marking pints manually on it and using getpts for **2d points** to calculate P matrix.

Answer (score 0):

```
% Create a 17 by 12 matrix named "store" and populate it with zeros
store = zeros(17, 12);
for i = 1:17
    store(i, :) = % Replace the zeros by what you want to store here
end
```

> `store(1, :)--->first row` "`:`"points to all of its columns
>
> `store(2, :)--->second row` "`:`"points to all of its columns
>
> so on...
>
> `store(i, :)--->i-th row` "`:`"points to all of its columns